# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in doctrine like query

Tags: php, doctrine

```
 `$qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('u')
       ->from('user\models\User','u')
        ;
 if(is_array($filters) && count($filters) > 0)
        {
            foreach($filters as $k => $v){
                if($k != 'search')
                    $qb->andWhere("u.".$k."='".$v."'");
                else
                    $qb->andWhere('u.firstname LIKE :firstname')->setParameter('firstname',"$v%");
            }
        }`
```

the above code gives me the following error.
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('u.firstname', $qb->expr()->literal("%$v%")));
```

this solved my answer